# TensorFlow: Compile Error for OpenCl Install from Source

Tags: compilation, tensorflow, opencl, fedora-25

Hello I have followed the Instructions to install from source and after running ./configure with clang/++ and ComputeCpp path provided and Yes to OpenCL.

With Bazel command :

```
bazel build --config opt --config=sycl //tensorflow/tools  /pip_package:build_pip_package
```

I get the following compile error:

```
clang++: symbol lookup error: /usr/bin/clang++: undefined symbol: LLVMInitializeMipsAsmParser
```

I looked up the Symbol and it belongs to Rust which is not installed on my system nor can I see how to install it or the library required by this Install of TensorFlow. It only happens when I install for OpenCL. So it seems it is used for OpenCL along with ComputeCpp. I am installing on Fedora 25 (Yey)

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated. Also how do you stop it from downloading everytime you run ./Configure can it not just read that it already has the files downloaded and if so where?

Thanks
Hbyte

Comment: The problem seems to be that you have clang++ installed and this is being used for compilation instead of compute++, which is the compiler for ComputeCpp. I don't have a specific solution for you but I'll try to find out how you might be able to resolve this.

Comment: I inserted ompute++ and have now found that header files located in my /usr/include path are not being used. stdarg.h being one example. I have now to ensure that all include paths are being accessed by compute++. This requires an edit to the Bazel build files but this is difficult. I would love to know if there is a ready made whl package for Fedora using OpenCL. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

First off all, Fedora 25 is not officially supported by ComputeCpp yet. Although, we will do all we can to help.

You shouldn't need to change any of the bazel build files.
Could you confirm where is ComputeCpp installed?

> I inserted ompute++ and have now found that header files located in my /usr/include path are not being used.

Do you mean that your system headers are not picked after configuring TF to use OpenCL?

From TensorFlow set up point of view you should point 
`./configure` to what's the location.. there is no need to copy headers / binaries anywhere.

for instance my ComputeCpp is in my home directory

`Do you wish to build TensorFlow with OpenCL support? [y/N] y
OpenCL support will be enabled for TensorFlow
Do you wish to build TensorFlow with CUDA support? [y/N] 
No CUDA support will be enabled for TensorFlow
which: no clang++-3.6 in (/usr/lib64/ccache:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/home/luke/.local/bin:/home/luke/bin)
Please specify which C++ compiler should be used as the host C++ compiler. [Default is ]: /usr/bin/clang++
Please specify which C compiler should be used as the host C compiler. [Default is /usr/local/bin/clang-3.6]: /usr/bin/clang
Please specify the location where ComputeCpp for SYCL 1.2 is installed. [Default is /usr/local/computecpp]: /home/luke/ComputeCpp-CE-0.1.2-Linux`

As of the whl package, it boils down to Google, but as far as I am aware TensorFlow is not officially supporting Fedora 25 either.

If you have a fix for the build system please create Pull Request :)

What happens if you choose GCC for your host compiler?

Would it be possible to open an issue on GitHub to track the progress of this?

Comment: ComputeCpp is in /usr/local/  . I have tried using GCC instead of clang but as yet havent tried G++ instead of clang++ I am waiting for my Broadband to be fixed and then I will have another go. Bazel keeps re-downloading its files everytime I run ./config and bazel build so each time I have to wait.

Comment: Using compute++ lacks /usr/include/linux - which is in the include path and it cannot find stdarg.h - /usr/include/c++/6.2.1/tr1/. However this is also in ComputeCpp's include path for clang. Can you tell me for these missing headers how to instruct ./config to use them is it simply -I/usr/include/linux ?

Comment: I read online that they needed to be included in a bazel BUILD file. It would nce to have a package for Fedora using OpenCl. The install of the CPU only version doesnt include OpenCL. Yes you can open an issue on GitHub please do. I will just go through all of the errors and try to fix them - but I need to know what arguments I can provide to bazel build to include these directorys - havent a clue. Or provide them to config, I'd prefer Bazel as this saves time each time I run config I must redownload. Thanks

Comment: You don't need to include any headers such as /usr/include/linux. We have tested the setup with Ubuntu and CentOS using gcc. Can you try using with this tested configuration? Are you following the setup guide? https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/master/get_started/os_setup